# SSRS & asp.net - passing parameters from .net to ssrs in report viewer

Tags: .net, reporting-services, reportviewer

I am about to embark in using a report viewer in my .net page. I have a page that will search for a catgory, upon a button click, the category chosen will pass into the parameter of report viewer.

Now, given that I am a newbie to both SSRS and .net, I'd just like a bit of advice on how to tackle this.

Should I make the report in SSRS first and include the parameters in this report or can I make the report without the parameters specified, then programmatically enter this in the codebehind?

Basically, I know what I would like to do but not sure the best approach to take.

If anyone can offer advice, I would be most grateful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Welcome to the world of ASP.NET reporting!  SSRS has a bit of a learning curve, but once you get the hang of it, I'm sure you'll enjoy working with it.

I recommend creating the report first and including your parameters.

You can then set the parameter values in your code-behind like this:

```vb
Private Sub SetReportParameters(ByVal viewer As ReportViewer)
    ''# use parameters to pass info to report
    Dim myStartDate As New ReportParameter("StartDate", Request.QueryString("startDt"))
    Dim myEndDate As New ReportParameter("EndDate", Request.QueryString("endDt"))
    Dim myRegion As New ReportParameter("Region", region)
    Try
        ''# add parameters to the report
        viewer.LocalReport.SetParameters( _
            New ReportParameter() {myStartDate, myEndDate, myRegion})
    Catch ex As Exception
        ErrorLabel.Text = DATABASE_ERROR_MSG
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: I changed comments in the code block to start with {''#} instead of {'} for better syntax highlighting.

Comment: Thanks Dubs - I've been having a play today and I can see a lot of potential. now it's a case of weighing up the pros and cons of the different ways or presenting data!

Comment: If you are looking for examples of what you can do with SSRS, this site has some very advanced reporting techniques: http://www.devx.com/dbzone/Article/37703/1954

There's a few good blogs out there too, like this one: http://blogs.msdn.com/brianhartman/

Have fun and good luck!